# Android Deeplink and Fallback to URL call javascript function

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to call javascript function in "fallback to URL" of intent, but its not working

I'm Using below code

```
<script>
    function test(){
        alert('yes');
   }
</script>

<a href="intent://<url>#Intent;scheme=<app_name>;S.browser_fallback_url=javascript:test();end" >click to launch </a>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?